# Hide div on video play

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm using video.js here:
http://dev-carlyle.sassafrascreative.com/
I want the text over the video to disappear when the video's play function is triggered. right now it works sometimes and then sometimes it doesn't. Currently I'm using jquery's hide function but there has to be a better - more reliable - way to do this. Any ideas?

this is a snippet of my current solution, if you can call it that...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".vjs-big-play-button").click(function(){
$(".banner-email").hide(1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could put a transparent image of the player underneath the text and on clicking the text you can replace the same "id" of <p> with the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the video.js docs it has this functionality built in

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#events

```
var myFunc = function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  $(".banner-email").hide(1000);
};
myPlayer.on("play", myFunc);
```

This is better because once the video is paused you can make the email thing come back up. It's a custom event listener fired by video.js

> play  Fired whenever the media begins or resumes playback.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) function for this like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.vjs-big-play-button',function(){
       $(".banner-email").hide(1000);
    });
</script>
```